# / vs. \ in relative paths to executables in CMD and the C system function

Tags: c, windows

Consider the following CMD session on Windows 10, lines starting with `#` are comments:

```
# We have this simple program
D:\testdir>type prg.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf("Hello prg");
  return 0;
}
# This is "realgcc.exe (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project) 6.2.0"
D:\testdir>gcc prg.c -o prg
D:\testdir>prg.exe
Hello prg
D:\testdir>md dir
D:\testdir>cd dir
D:\testdir\dir>..\prg.exe
Hello prg
# This does not work however
D:\testdir\dir>../prg.exe
'..' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
# But this does
D:\testdir\dir>"../prg.exe"
Hello prg
# Now we want to call the same program, from the same directory,
# but from C instead, so we create this file
D:\testdir\dir>type call.c
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  system("..\\prg.exe");
  return 0;
}
D:\testdir\dir>gcc call.c -o call
D:\testdir\dir>call.exe
Hello prg
# Now to the question: If we modify the system function call
# to the following -- why doesn't it work?
D:\testdir\dir>type call.c
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  system("\"../prg.exe\"");
  return 0;
}
D:\testdir\dir>gcc call.c -o call
D:\testdir\dir>call.exe
'..' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

So apparently calling `system` is not the same as running the command in a CMD session interactively? Are the quotes stripped for some reason? Is there another syntax that can be used to invoke executables in other directories using relative paths containing using `/` instead of `\` as separators?

(I noticed this when trying to make a Cygwin program and a usual Windows program talk to each other.)

**Edit**: Apparently, this works:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  system("\"\"../prg.exe\"\"");
  return 0;
}
```

Possibly related, in CMD,

```
cmd /c ""../prg.exe""
```

works, whereas this don't

```
cmd /c "../prg.exe"
```

So it seems that some additional quotes are needed for some reason in the `system` call?

Comment: The *filesystem* considers `/` and `\ ` to be equivalent when used as separators between pathname components. The *command interpreter* considers that `/` separates words; so for `cmd.exe`, the command `../prg.exe` consists of two words, `..` and `/prg.exe`. When you enclose it in quotes, `cmd` takes it as one word and looks it up in the filesystem, where it works, because for the filesystem `/` and `\ ` are equivalent when used as pathname component separators.

Comment: @AlexP: Ok, thanks, the explains the behaviour in the shell, but not why two "layers" of quotes are needed in the `system` call.

Comment: The first set of double quotes are consumed by the system call, pretty much the same as `cmd /c ""../prg.exe""` consumes the first set of quotes. So it pretty much uses the first set to ensure it carries the complete string in readable form to the next session.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard: What do you mean "consume"? Where is this behaviour documented? (One wonders e.g. what other things are thrown away!)

Comment: "/" isn't a regular delimiter in CMD (i.e. the set of whitespace, equals, comma, and semicolon). It's used for switches (options). Initially "../prg.exe arg" is tokenized as the command "../prg.exe" and argument "arg". Then the dispatch loop calls `cmd!FindAndFix`, which splits the command into ".." as the command to run and "/prg.exe" as an argument. The latter gets prepended as "/prg.exe arg" in the argument string. Using quotes prevents this split.

Comment: `system` is implemented via `cmd.exe /c cmdline`. The behavior of `cmd /c` is clearly documented in the `cmd /?` help. You're getting the old behavior that removes the first and last quote.

Comment: Also, to clarify, slash and backslash are *not equivalent* at the filesystem level. Filesystems are implemented as native NT devices, and in the native object namespace only backslash is a path delimiter. (For filesystems only, slash is reserved as an invalid character; other NT object types such as device names and registry keys allow slash as a name character.) To implement the Windows API and optionally as a convenience for native applications, the runtime library in ntdll.dll has functions to convert DOS and WinAPI style paths to native paths, which includes replacing slash with backslash.

Comment: For example, if you use the "\\?\" prefix to work with long paths or filenames that are otherwise reserved in the WinAPI namespace (e.g. DOS device names and names that end with trailing dots or spaces), this prefix completely bypasses runtime path processing. In this case you *must* use backslash as the path separator.

Comment: @cic I think eryksun pretty much explained the documented portion by just running `cmd /?`.

Comment: @eryksun: Thank you for your detailed answer. When I was saying that I was wondering where this behaviour is documented I was referring to the connection between `system` and CMD. There's documentation for CMD, e.g. in `cmd /?` as you say, but when looking at e.g. [the Windows `system`, `_wsystem` functions documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/system-wsystem), I don't see any mention of this. More specifically, I was expected something saying that `system(...)` is equivalent to `cmd /c ...` or similar. ...

Comment: ... Because `system` throwing away some of its input seems like important behaviour to document; but maybe one can argue that `system` is platform-dependent and each platform can do whatever it likes. But I don't think there's anything similar happening on e.g. Linux with Bash, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: (Or maybe one should look at documentation for the C library implementation the GCC variant I'm testing here (but I can't find any such documentation)... Because the behaviour could possibly differ between Visual Studio's implementation and the library used by this GCC variant.)

Comment: It's assumed that a developer knows that the default command interpreter set in `%ComSpec%` is cmd.exe, and that the way to run a command is with the `/c` option, and anyone curious would be able to run `cmd /?`. What they don't tell us, and should, is that it doesn't use the `/d` option to prevent running CMD's registered "AutoRun" command. They also fail to inform us that it calls `CreateProcess` (via `[w]spawnlpe`) with `bInheritHandles`, which is a common source of leaked handles.

Comment: To answer my own last question, this GCC variant is apparently using [msvcrt.dll](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/wiki2/The%20case%20against%20msvcrt.dll/) as its C runtime. The source code for some Microsoft C runtime versions are available when installing Visual Studio (assuming the correct parts are installed etc.), and the implementation I looked at indeed passes the command to the command interpreter in the way described in the comments here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for all helpful comments, I now understand what's happening. I did not consider how the command (i.e., the argument to `system`) is actually passed to the "command interpreter" when asking this question, and this is critical to consider to understand why the the outer quotes disappear.

On Windows, calling `system("command")` is essentially the the same thing as spawning a new `cmd.exe` process with the arguments `/c` and `command`. (On [Linux and similar OSes](https://linux.die.net/man/3/system), we would instead have an equivalence with `sh -c command`.)

The problem here, however, is that in most cases Windows' CMD will strip the first and last quote character when a command is passed through the `/c` flag. This is stated in the documentation given by `cmd /?`:

```
[...]

If /C or /K is specified, then the remainder of the command line after
the switch is processed as a command line, where the following logic is
used to process quote (") characters:

1.  If all of the following conditions are met, then quote characters
    on the command line are preserved:

    - no /S switch
    - exactly two quote characters
    - no special characters between the two quote characters,
      where special is one of: &<>()@^|
    - there are one or more whitespace characters between the
      two quote characters
    - the string between the two quote characters is the name
      of an executable file.

2.  Otherwise, old behavior is to see if the first character is
    a quote character and if so, strip the leading character and
    remove the last quote character on the command line, preserving
    any text after the last quote character.

[...]
```